# How use Excel formula to add new row in table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-surface

I'm using Excel 2013 on a Microsoft Surface 2 (which is an RT ARM machine).  It's my understanding that the Surface 2/RT version of Office does not allow scripting or forms.

I'm trying to create a "button" in a worksheet that will somehow cause the inserting of a new blank row in a neighboring table (on another tab of same workbook) and would then copy over the new data in some cells over to that new table row.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe cannot be done with formulas. You would need VBA and that is not supported on your Excel version.

You may need to re-organise your data architecture. You can have an Excel Table where each row has formulas that pull data from somewhere else on the sheet.

But if you have one area of the sheet that serves as an input form and another area of the sheet/workbook that serves as a database of previously entered forms, then there is no formula way to move that data into the table. You would need to use the table row as the input mechanism.